# Delete all files in a folder

Tags: vba, file, kill

I have the below code to try search for all files in my downloads folder and then delete them all however it's returning an error message based on the kill function not having enough arguments, any ideas?

```
Sub Kill ()

Dim aFile As String
aFile = "C:\Test\Test\Downloads\*.*"
If Len(Dir$(aFile)) > 0 Then
    Kill aFile
End If

End Sub
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 12):

A more simple way:

```html
Sub Del()
  Kill "C:\FolderName\*.*"
End Sub
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) helps to improve the quality of your response. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: If you use this code and the folder is empty, it will generate an error: "Execution error: 53 / file not found". So it's indeed simple but not reliable at 100%. And I don't think that adding something like "On Error Resume Next" is a good idea...

Comment: True, so better doing it like @Ashok answer

Comment: Also when a file is in use by an application you get the Execution error: 70 / permission denied. I prefer using the FileSystemObject as @John-Alexiou does.

Answer (score 7):

Add a reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` in the VBA environment

[image: ref]

[image: scr]

The declare in a `Module` the following line

```
Global fso As New FileSystemObject
```

Now you can use all the nice and modern I/O functions. For example:

```
Public Sub TDELFOL()    
    Dim path As String, f As File
    path = fso.GetSpecialFolder(TemporaryFolder)
    path = fso.BuildPath(path, "MyTempFolder")
    If fso.FolderExists(path) Then
        For Each f In fso.GetFolder(path).Files
            f.Delete Force = True
        Next
        fso.DeleteFolder path, Force = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I've found what my problem is, I'm trying to delete all the files which automatically get saved into the C: Downloads on my computer so they're not in a folder within that location, just into users and then downloads. Any ideas on how I can clear all my downloads through VBA?

Comment: In `C:\Downloads`, or `C:\Users\<userid>\Downloads`? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44162807/edit) the question with the _specifics_ and be clear of your intent. Maybe provide an example of before and after.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't very clear, I've used the coding you put above however because C:\Downloads isn't a folder it isn't deleting any files. If I put a folder within the location it will delete that folder but I want to clear all files within downloads. Does that make sense? Thanks,

Comment: I have edited the answer to show deleting of all the files in a folder first, and then the folder itself (if needed). I hope you can adapt the above to your needs.

Answer (score 6):

You should *not* name macros as the in built functions. Just changing the macros with the same coding resolves the issues...

```
Sub Kill1 ()

Dim aFile As String
aFile = "C:\Test\Test\Downloads\*.*"
If Len(Dir$(aFile)) > 0 Then
    Kill aFile
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You should not**

Comment: Edit the question for your correction, rather than adding it as a comment. Also, please format your code as code.

Answer (score 0):

```
' For deleting all files in a folder, this code worked for me.  See comments added to the end of each line for an explanation of what the code is doing.

Dim fso As Object, myFileNameDel As String, file As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") ' Connect to the file system
For Each file In fso.GetFolder("C:\folder\").Files ' Go into each file of the folder "C:\folder\" - change the path to the file path in which you want to delete files
    myFileNameDel = file.Name ' Get the file name (this line is not necessary but may help with troubleshooting)
    file.Delete ' Delete the file found - this will occur each time it finds a file in the specified folder
Next file ' find the next file in the specified folder
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**